# Rails + Postgres db:migrate failing on missing data rather than generating it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, system-administration

I'm trying to set up a development environment for an existing rails project, but keep running into issues around migrating the DB.

Here's the config/database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  timeout: 5000
  username: postgres
  password:
  database: myapp_development

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_production
```

I'v installed the 'pg' gem (v0.18.3), launched postgres and created the proper role. Here's the output of `\list` from the Postgres shell:

```
postgres=# \list
                                       List of databases
         Name         |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   
----------------------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 myapp_development    | raul     | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 myapp_test           | raul     | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 postgres             | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 template0            | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
                      |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1            | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
                      |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
(7 rows)
```

I get this error:

```
$ rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "pools" does not exist
LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"pools"'::regclass
                                          ^
:               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                     pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
                FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                  ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
               WHERE a.attrelid = '"pools"'::regclass
                 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
               ORDER BY a.attnum
```

Comment: @muistooshort I've updated the question. Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it guys! It was actually a bad line in my `Gemfile`.

Specifically `gem 'factory_girl', :require => false`

Please comment if you know why that may have broken rake.